# Forecasting asset returns using index models in R

Tags: r, forecasting, finance

How do you forecast returns and the associated risk in R using index models? How do you represent risk in multi index models as a single value in R?

Comment: This question is too broad, that it's almost off-topic. First, it's R focused, second it's from finance area - at least the most complications come from the domain. It's not an appropriately focused question for stats forum

Comment: It is too late to migrate, but this would be a better fit at e.g. quantitative finance SE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lm` function for a single index model (SIM):

```
rm=market return  
rs=stock return for single stock  

sim=lm(rs~rm,data=returns);  
summary(sim);
```

This returns a model fitted by least squares.

If you want predictions and you have a new data set with market return values named as `newdata`, then you can get predictions this way:

```
predicts=predict(sim,data=newdata);
```

For risk metrics, I think beta-vector is a good measure since it describes covariance between a single stock's return and market risk in a single index model.

For a multiple index model (MIM), you can use the following code:

```
electret=return of stock for company producing electricity  
gas=commodity price index for gas  
oil=commodity price index for oil  

mim=lm(electret~gas+oil,data=yourdata);  
summary(mim);
```

Betas tell you how much stock return is affected by movements in these indices.

Comment: There are many problems to model return with just linear models. First, most of the time, return are not normally distributed. So you may need to take some transformations before fitting. More than that, they are auto-correlated which is not good in linear model as you proposed. Volatility would be another problem and this list goes on! Time series models are much more appropriate than linear models ...